# selenium WebDriverException driver unexpectedly exited

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium in python and for some reason I cannot modify the PATH so I can only specify the location of browser driver. However, I tried several drivers and none of them worked.

Environment: Windows 7, Anaconda3-python3.6.1, selenium3.4.3, chrome59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit), chromedriver2.30 (win32).

Here are a part of the code I have tried and the corresponding error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("I:\chromedriver.exe")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in  driver = webdriver.Chrome("I:\chromedriver.exe")

File "C:\Users\yz\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in **init**
    self.service.start()

File "C:\Users\yz\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()

File "C:\Users\yz\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)

WebDriverException: Service I:\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Comment: is your `path` to the driver correct? should be something like this format `C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs`

Comment: I have tried `driver = webdriver.Chrome("I:\\chromedriver")` but got the same error

Comment: try `I:\\chromedriver.exe`

Comment: I did, yielded the same error

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While working with `Selenium` 3.4.3, `chromedriver` v2.30 and `Google Chrome` 59.0 to initiate the `WebDriver` instance we need to pass the absolute path of the `chromedriver` through the argument `executable_path` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @MehmetKurtipek Did you notice the escaped _back slashes_ ?

Comment: yup, OP did try that in comments :)